# Can ReSharper be trained to rename interface parameters?

Tags: c#, resharper

I have an interface in some referenced third-party assembly, such as:

```
public interface ITextHandler
{
  void Handle(string text)
}
```

And in my own project, I take on specific meaning by inheriting this into my own interface:

```
public interface INameHandler : ITextHandler
{
}
```

When using a tool like ReSharper, I might start off with:

```
public class Foo : INameHandler
{
}
```

Resharper will show an error I can click on and "Implement Interfaces". The result yields:

```
public class Foo : INameHandler
{
  public void Handle(string text)
  {
  }
}
```

Is there any way to tell ReSharper that I want to rename the parameter to be more specific? I'd like it to implement "name" instead of "text":

```
public class Foo : INameHandler
{
  public void Handle(string name)
  {
  }
}
```

Is there a resharper comment or something I can add to INameHandler that redefines the default parameter name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest that you *don't* do this. Indeed, just last night I ended up going to some effort to put my parameter names *back* to the one declared in the interface (I suspect I changed my mind in the interface later).

Consider this code:

```
Foo handler = new Foo();
handler.Handle(name: "Hello");
```

Now consider this harmless-looking refactoring, on the grounds of preferring to declare a variable via the interface type instead of the concrete type:

```
INameHandler handler = new Foo();
handler.Handle(name: "Hello");
```

If your parameter names are different, you'll get a compile-time error. It can be worse than this - you could end up with code that *compiles* but changes *meaning* if you reorder existing parameter names. [Nasty, nasty stuff.](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/07/03/evil-code-of-the-day.aspx)

I'm not saying this *will* happen - but it's *a* good reason (IMO) to be careful when choosing parameter names, particularly in interfaces, and sticking with those names in implementations.

(Hmmm... maybe I ought to write a little tool to find all violations of that... could be handy.)

Comment: Wouldn't this only matter with optional parameters?  If Handle must take a string, why would you call it by name?

Comment: @MattJohnson: For clarity, or potentially to change overload resolution. While named arguments are *often* used with optional parameters, they're distinct features which can be used independently. In particular, if a method has several parameters of the same type and it's not immediately obvious which argument means what, specifying the argument names can really help. Consider `MessageBox.Show(text: "This is the text in the box", caption: "Bang!")`